# Once again: Why my ImageView is not refreshing?

Tags: android, imageview, invalidation, translate-animation

I know this question has been answered several times before, but this newbie could not find an answer that worked.

I tried to implement a panorama viewer using a TouchImageView (extends ImageView). First I tried with TranslateAnimation, but also failed (my question got [no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963836/can-a-panorama-viewer-effect-be-done-with-translateanimation), so I presume this is not possible with TouchImageView).

Then I tried the hard way, using ImageView.matrix, moving a little bit, pausing, moving a little bit, pausing... Well, at least that was my idea.

The problem is that I only see the panorama in its final position after 4 or 5 seconds showing nothing. I even put two `ImageView.invalidate();`, without any success. I tried using Threads and AsyncTasks without success either (problem with those is that they has to update the main UI, otherwise I get an Exception; but it looks wrong to me to use AsyncTask to update the UI thread). Well, I tried everything I can think of.

Anyway, below is my simple code (the AsyncTask try, but with everything I do inside). Observe the `foto.invalidate();` in the `onPreExecute` method that is not obeyed (why?). There are some lines commented for you to see what else I tried.

My simple code, where `foto` is the (Touch)ImageView:

```
class animatepanorama extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    float scale = foto.cropScale * foto.baseScale;
    Matrix m = foto.matrix;
    protected void onPreExecute(Void arg0) {
        m.setScale(scale, scale);
        foto.Scale = foto.cropScale;
        foto.setImageMatrix(m);
        foto.invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        //synchronized(foto) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(25);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    m.setScale(scale, scale);
                    m.postTranslate(-i * scale * 8, 0);
                    foto.setImageMatrix(m);
                    foto.invalidate();
                }
            }
        });
        //}
        // }}).start();
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void arg0) {
        foto.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of running it from doinbackground on the UI thread, use publishProgress and onProgressUpdate? The problem is doinbackground does not run on the uithread but "in the background" so for all UI updates it has to pass this to onprogressupdate.

Change your Async to this:

```
class animatepanorama extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
```

The Integer parameter can then be used to call onProgressUpdate

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        publishProgress(0);

    }
```

And override this:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    if (values[0] == 0) {
        m.setScale(scale, scale);
        m.postTranslate(-i * scale * 8, 0);
        foto.setImageMatrix(m);
        foto.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat idea! Ok, followed your suggestion, and it **kind** of works. I mean "kind" because it is not reliable for some reason. Sometimes it plays the panorama, sometimes it doesn't. No idea why. I'm looking at the logcat, and there is nothing! I'll continue thinking about this, but you gave me a good idea. Thanks!!

Comment: Well what you really should be using is a surfaceview. Watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUmId0rwsBQ&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A

Comment: What seems to be happening with my code is that I cannot stop the asynctask, not even with `.cancel(true)` (my asynctask is indeed an infinite loop, but it should stop with `.cancel(true)`, me thinks. Even after I exit my app, it keeps running (I can see it eating 10% of CPU). - I will look at SurfaceView, but looks overcomplicated for what I want. Silly me that thought that this was a simple `TranslateAnimation` thing....

Comment: You could perhaps extend the view class which is much simpler. Also to cancel you could just make your i value 100 or something...

Comment: I managed to stop the asynctask even with an infinite loop, calling `break` if the task is cancelled (got the idea from a code around here). So I am closer. Anyway, I will take a look to surfaceview. Thanks again!!